# Using TensorFlow Audio Recognition Model on iOS

Tags: ios, tensorflow

I'm trying to use the TensorFlow audio recognition model (`my_frozen_graph.pb`, generated here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio_recognition) on iOS.

But the iOS code `NSString* network_path = FilePathForResourceName(@"my_frozen_graph", @"pb");` in the TensorFlow Mobile's `tf_simple_example` project outputs this error message: `Could not create TensorFlow Graph: Not found: Op type not registered 'DecodeWav'`.

Anyone knows how I can fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are using the pre-build Tensorflow from Cocapods? It probably does not have that op type, so you should build it yourself from latest source.

From [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/ios_build#building_the_tensorflow_ios_libraries_from_source):

> While Cocapods is the quickest and easiest way of getting started, you
>   sometimes need more flexibility to determine which parts of TensorFlow
>   your app should be shipped with. For such cases, you can build the iOS
>   libraries from the sources. [This guide](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/ios#building-the-tensorflow-ios-libraries-from-source) contains detailed instructions
>   on how to do that.

This might also be helpful: [[iOS] Add optional Selective Registration of Ops #14421](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/14421)

> **Optimization**
>
> The `build_all_ios.sh` script can take optional
>   command-line arguments to selectively register only for the operators
>   used in your graph.
>
> `tensorflow/contrib/makefile/build_all_ios.sh -a arm64 -g $HOME/graphs/inception/tensorflow_inception_graph.pb`
>
> Please note this
>   is an aggresive optimization of the operators and the resulting
>   library may not work with other graphs but will reduce the size of the
>   final library.

After the build is done you can check `/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/ops_to_register.h` for operations that were registered. (autogenerated during build with -g flag)

Comment: Thanks Antoni4 for the reply. No I tried manually built TensorFlow libraries, as in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15921. I'm supposed you also created this detailed TF github issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15921? Any luck? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jeff. Yes, I opened that issue. I'm still trying to get it working, but no luck yet. If I do get any further I will keep you posted. Please let me know if you have any luck too. Thanks! :)

Comment: Hi Antoni, please try the fix below and see if it also works for you.

Comment: Thanks for that Jeff I'll definitely try it later today

Answer (score 0):

Some progress: having realized the unregistered DecodeWav error is similar to the old familiar DecodeJpeg issue (#2883), I ran strip_unused on the pb as follows:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/strip_unused \
  --input_graph=/tf_files/speech_commands_graph.pb \
  --output_graph=/tf_files/stripped_speech_commands_graph.pb \
  --input_node_names=wav_data,decoded_sample_data \
  --output_node_names=labels_softmax \
  --input_binary=true
```

It does get rid of the DecodeWav op in the resulting graph. But running the new stripped graph on iOS now gives me an Op type not registered 'AudioSpectrogram' error.
Also there's no object file audio*.o generated after build_all_ios.sh is done, although AudioSpectrogramOp is specified in tensorflow/core/framework/ops_to_register.h:

```
Jeffs-MacBook-Pro:tensorflow-1.4.0 zero2one$ find  . -name decode*.o
./tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/obj/ios_ARM64/tensorflow/core/kernels/decode_bmp_op.o
./tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/obj/ios_ARM64/tensorflow/core/kernels/decode_wav_op.o
./tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/obj/ios_ARMV7/tensorflow/core/kernels/decode_bmp_op.o
./tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/obj/ios_ARMV7/tensorflow/core/kernels/decode_wav_op.o
./tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/obj/ios_ARMV7S/tensorflow/core/kernels/decode_bmp_op.o
./tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/obj/ios_ARMV7S/tensorflow/core/kernels/decode_wav_op.o
./tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/obj/ios_I386/tensorflow/core/kernels/decode_bmp_op.o
./tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/obj/ios_I386/tensorflow/core/kernels/decode_wav_op.o
./tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/obj/ios_X86_64/tensorflow/core/kernels/decode_bmp_op.o
./tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/obj/ios_X86_64/tensorflow/core/kernels/decode_wav_op.o
Jeffs-MacBook-Pro:tensorflow-1.4.0 zero2one$ find  . -name audio*_op.o
Jeffs-MacBook-Pro:tensorflow-1.4.0 zero2one$
```

Answer (score 0):

Just verified that Pete's fix (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15921) is good:
add this line `tensorflow/core/ops/audio_ops.cc` to the file `tensorflow/contrib/makefile/tf_op_files.txt` and run `tensorflow/contrib/makefile/build_all_ios.sh` again (`compile_ios_tensorflow.sh "-O3"` itself used to work for me after adding a line to the tf_op_files.txt, but not anymore with TF 1.4).

Also, use the original model file, don't use the stripped version. Some note was added in the link above.